# Apache error "ProxyPass unknown Worker parameter" when using "upgrade=WebSocket"？

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy, websocket

I am trying to relay the WebSocket connection of V2Ray with Apache according to [This post](https://github.com/v2ray/v2ray-core/issues/747), and the snippet below worked before.

```
<LocationMatch "/{ws_path}}/">
    ProxyPass ws://127.0.0.1:{port}/{ws_path}/ upgrade=WebSocket
    ProxyAddHeaders Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RequestHeader set Host %{HTTP_HOST}s
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-For %{REMOTE_ADDR}s
</LocationMatch>
```

However now I wanted to replicate it on a new machine, Apache2 cannot be started, and the error message says:

```
Jun 13 11:22:22 localhost apachectl[1519]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 32 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/whc2001cloud.tk.conf:
Jun 13 11:22:22 localhost apachectl[1519]: ProxyPass unknown Worker parameter
Jun 13 11:22:22 localhost apachectl[1519]: Action 'start' failed.
Jun 13 11:22:22 localhost apachectl[1519]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Jun 13 11:22:22 localhost systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 13 11:22:22 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

If I take away the `upgrade=WebSocket` parameter, Apache2 starts, but V2Ray is unable to make connection correctly. I have already enabled `mod_ssl, mod_proxy, mod_proxy_wstunnel` and other related modules.

Comment: are you using apache 2.2 or apache 2.4?

Comment: @c4f4t0r It's Apache 2.4.25.

Comment: @Wwhc2001 I think that you are using the parameter option in the wrong way https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html, in any case, from doc, it sould work without this parameter by default

Comment: @c4f4t0r Thanks, seems like it does work without that parameter. The connection failure is due to an invalid DNS record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Forgot to post the answer instead of commenting back then

Just remove the `upgrade=WebSocket` patameter and it should work without any problem.